# How to build a DIY HEPA filters for a vaccum cleaners (no spare part for sale)?

Tags: appliances

I bought a vacuum cleaner* from a store (AmazonBasics) which works with 3 types of filters. Unfortunately, the company doesn't sell spare filters. So I'm looking for a DIY way to replace these filters. 
[image]
The most difficult one to replace seems to be the **flat** filter (1): the materials look like the thin sheet of fabric (or paper?) used in the FFP3 HEPA mask, but where to find a sheet of such material? What material would you use?

The "the motor filter" (3)  looks the easiest to change, it looks like classic HEPA filters glued in the plastic. I guess I could simply cut it in a bigger filter and (hot)glue it inside the frame. The cylinder of foam (2) is a basic pre-filter made of basic polyurethane foam. A piece of foam mattress might do the job.

*"AmazonBasics Cylinder Bagless Vacuum Cleaner, 1.5 L, 700 W"

Comment: It might be easier to just invest in an air compressor and blow them clean (reverse airflow) periodically. I have a similar bagless vac and I've been just blowing the filters and washing the foam ones for 8 years

Comment: @CaiusJard "It might be easier to just invest in an air compressor". Unfortunately HEPA filter don't work that way. You are talking about clogging issue which concern other filters (filtering bigger particules).

Comment: How do you think a HEPA filter differs from other filters? I interpreted your question to be "how do I get my vacuum working again, given that no replacement filters are available, and the filter is rammed solid with dust?" - you take the filters out, take them outside and blow them out with a high speed stream of compressed air. It won't renew the filter to as-new condition, but all the dust you see fly out of it is indicative that a) air is passing and b) the filter can now trap a similar amount of dust again. Like wringing a cloth out doesn't dry it, but it can still soak up more water

Comment: The purpose of HEPA filter is to filter the fine particule (usually till PM2.5). After a while, the filter let them pass through, so it's useless. You need to replace it (unless you don't mind breathing high amount of particules―it's not about allergy, but basic hygiene). There is no way to make it work again (washing, compressor don't work). (Btw, you can test the efficiency of HEPA filters using DIY PM detector like the Luftdaten one which cost 20$ to build)

Comment: ps; if you need the highest amount of filtration available for allergy reasons it may be wise to invest in a vacuum that you can get spares for, but see how you go with blowing them out. I'd recommend you give the vac a short run with no filters at all (and then again with all the filters installed) outside too, as I typically find when I blow my filters out that some small puff of dust emerges from the vac upon first startup

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you about how HEPA filters work; as they become progressively blocked their filtration power increases, not decreases - it's the reason your vac stops working.. Unless you mean the internal structure of the filter fibers becomes destroyed and unable to trap down to the level of a new filter - in which case, it seems a reasonable assertion. A filter that has been blown clean might not trap all the 0.3 micron dirt a new one would, but your vacuum cleaner will clean the house again. Extreme allergies notwithstanding it would suit most people

Comment: there are 2 misunderstandings: 1) my question isn't about "a vacuum cleaner that doesn't work", but "HEPA that doesn't work". A vacuum with a dead filter will still suck the dust, but so will your lungs. 2) I guess the second/main misunderstanding is cultural: you confuse "allergy" with "hygiene". You don't need to be "allergic" to protect yourself against the PMs, as you don't need to be allergic to wash your hand after going to the bathroom. Hygiene is cultural: some (few) sub-cultures take air pollution (or handwashing) seriously.

Comment: (And no, blowing a HEPA filter won't help. Look for Thomas Talhelm experiments: https://smartairfilters.com/en/blog/wash-clean-hepa/ )

Comment: "Man who sells air filters writes blog saying you should always buy new filters" - wouldn't have expected that. However, you're clearly deeply invested in what you consider to be a hygienic environment so I'm quite puzzled why you're determined to get by using a low grade vacuum cleaner for which you have to make your own filters. Examine your requirements and obtain something appropriate for purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You ask "where to buy a sheet of material that is has dust filtering properties"?

--> a vacuum cleaner bag!?

Also look into car air filters; they often have a folded paper manifestation. Engine air filters are unlikely to trap to HEPA levels but cabin air pollen filters etc might. If you suffer allergies but are fine breathing in your car on a pollen laden summers day, hacking up the cabin air filter for your model may suit your needs

ps: the foam filter can be washed with water and dried; the foam filter in a Dyson bears pictograms inviting the user to do this regularly. It advises not to run the vac with a wet filter

Comment: "vacuum cleaner bag" Great idea! Indeed, some of these bags are "HEPA"!

Comment: Cody use those HEPA vacuum cleaner bag (for his Hazardous Environment Suit!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsq6OO4CCHQ&t=125s

Answer (score 1):

There's a 'lot of similar materials out there that will let you build your own versions for a lower price than the store, and since you can't even get your model's filters, this is about the only way to do it for you.

If you do a search for "Mobile Home Foam Filter", you'll find a wide variety of "pre-filter" material. That foam won't last forever, so you'll need to replace it at some point, even if you wash it. I've washed those filters before, and they can still have a lot of gunk and fuzz still attached, which still doesn't want to come off.

Some vacuums use a fluffy pre-filter, along with the foam pre-filter. If you search for "white Pre-Filter", you can find that material.  And some use an activated carbon filter, which can be found by searching for exactly that, "activated carbon filter".

You can also find large amounts of HEPA filter material by searching for "hepa furnace filter". These are generally fairly large, pre-folded sheets that can be cut down and used however you need. It might be tricky to get it fitted just like the original filter, but it'll be better than nothing.

BTW, vacuum bags are getting harder to find and may not have as much material as a furnace filter can, with all it's pleating. Furnace filters are really easy to find and more are becoming HEPA filters as more and more people are becoming concerned with allergens in the air.

And this article talks about doing something similar. It has some links to specific material which may or may not still be available. It's geared more towards an air purifier than a vacuum, but it's similar enough that the info should be helpful.

http://www.air-purifier-power.com/doityourselfhepadyi120510.html

FYI, I did most of my searches on Amazon, but the majority of the stuff I found can be purchased at big box stores and home improvement stores, too. I'd recommend doing your initial material searching online, then get equivalent materials at wherever you do your shopping normally. You often get more options and feedback online than in-store, so your decisions can be more informed before spending money.

This isn't going to be exactly a inexpensive fix, but it will cost less than buying from someone hoarding your discontinued filters. It'll also be less expensive than having a company custom make a filter for you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible subtitute materials (or combo of) you might consider for substitution in making a DIY filter

- coffee filters
- quilt batting
- garden weed barrier
- flannel
- face masks
- disposable shoe cover booties.
- canvas drop cloth
- multiple pieces of rice or tissue paper.
- upholstery liner

Comment: That is nine answers.  This site works best with one answer per post so they may be voted upon and accepted separately.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the question wasn't about any filter, but a HEPA filter (which should block very small particulate matter). (The comment above is ridiculous, on the stack exchange you get 1000 people playing the police, for every single contributor who try to help, like you did)